# office.js replace Word table ooxml embeds the table into a new table

Tags: office-js

I have a Word table row with some cells bookmarked.  I want to clone the row with similar but modified bookmarks.  From what I have read I would want to use ooXml to achieve this - I don't see how to return a row or cell's range.

When trying to replace the table ooXml with the modified ooXml it embeds the table into what seems to be a new table.

I have a simple version below where I just retrieve the ooXml and insert it back and this same issue occurs:

```
Word.run(async context => {

  let tblRange = context.document.body.tables.getFirst().getRange();
  let tblXml = tblRange.getOoxml();

  await context.sync();

  tblRange.insertOoxml(tblXml.value, 'Replace');

  await context.sync();

});
```

This:
[image]

becomes:
[image]

is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly deleting the range before replacing it seems to do the trick:

```
Word.run(async context => {

  let tblRange = context.document.body.tables.getFirst().getRange();
  let tblXml = tblRange.getOoxml();

  await context.sync();

  tblRange.delete();   // <-- Added this line
  tblRange.insertOoxml(tblXml.value, 'Replace');

  await context.sync();

});
```

Comment: Glad to see you unblocked yourself!